# Component ID can be found by $find in Chrome console but not in external injection code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, asp.net-ajax

It has a web page using **MircrosoftAjax** to create the confirmation dialog that **ComponentID** could be found by **$find** (or Sys.Application.findComponent) in Chrome console and Sys.Application.getComponents got the ID Component list as well,but when I moved the code injecting into Content Script of Chrome extension,The result always returned **'NULL'** except for DOM operation . I just want to change the Component's property to achieve automatical confirmation without manual clicking,but it seems hard to do.
  This is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  

    Sys.Application.getComponents() //return 'NULL'
    Sys.Application.findComponent('sth')._ConfirmOnFormSubmit=true  //return 'Cannot set property '_ConfirmOnFormSubmit' of null '
    })

    function pageLoad(sender,args) {
//Sys.Application.initialize()
console.log($find('sth'))  //return 'NULL'
function confirm() {return true} //seems to approach the fact working well that bypassed the dialog in chrome console  but still not working in Content Script
}
```

Why has the different result between Content and Console? How should I do the right way?

I appreciate so much if someone can give me a solution.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see this behavior is that content scripts live in an [isolated context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment).
They don't have access to page's JavaScript and its state.

To test, you can open the console and at the top switch context from `<top frame>` to your extension's context. You'll see different console results.

To fix this situation, you need to inject yet another time, this time from the content script into the page's context; you can then communicate data between the two using custom events or `window.postMessage()`.

Here's a [canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) for that.

Comment: Oh,Xan! That's great for your help.
The answer for me is much useful and I will absorb the information gradually.

Thanks in advance ：）